# VB.NET - Grouping statements on one line

Tags: vb.net, syntax, conditional-statements

I want to put several statements on one line, including conditional statements that need to be grouped together.
I can do this:

```
x += 20 : y += 10 : If x > 400 Then x = 0
```

I want to have more than one statement under 'if'. It balks when I try to do this:

```
x += 20 : y += 10 : (If x > 400 Then x = 0 : y = 0)
```

or this:

```
x += 20 : y += 10 : If x > 400 Then (x = 0 : y = 0)
```

Is there a way?

Comment: [MSDN: If...Then...Else Statement (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx) discusses the syntax of single-line `If` statements, though its examples are similar to what you already have.

Comment: What's the reason behind wanting to do this?  It doesn't, as far as I can tell, contribute to the readability of your code, and it certainly has no positive impact on its efficiency.

Comment: Sometimes this makes it more readable for me, by having fewer lines of code. It may not for you, we are not all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x += 20 : y += 10 : If x > 400 Then x = 0 : y = 0
```

But I wouldn't recommend putting it on one line. It's a bit nasty to readability.

Comment: This answer is accurate in more than one way.  From testing the method shown here does work, but the advice is sound too.  I cannot fathom how doing this can help readability.

Comment: Yeah, I guess this would work, but is somewhat unclear as to whether the `y = 0` belongs to the `if` block or not. I wish it would work like in my second example, by enclosing the whole `if` logic in brackets, but unfortunately it does not. This way I could even add more statements after the `if` block.